# Start an Excel Axis at uneven value (e.g. 3) compared to labels (e.g. 5/10/15)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, axis

When I use an interval on an Excel x-axis for the labels of 5, Excel will use 0, 5, 10 for the labels.

When the start value is 3, Excel will use 3, 8, 13 for the labels.

How can I continue to use 5, 10, 15?

Comment: I suggest you add a region with coordinate, (5,0), (10,0), (15,0) ```, then insert Scatter with lines and markers to replace the Axis.

Comment: Did you try any of what was posted? It is always good to provide feedback.

Answer (score 1):

*At the risk of sounding ridiculous and insulting, neither of which am I trying to be:*

The start value should simply be 0. Otherwise, the start value of whatever chart you're using (you didn't specify in the question, making it difficult to help you, and I don't have enough reputation to comment) should be the lowest possible value you would expect to find rounded down to the nearest interval. So if say `Min(possibleValues) = 13` then your starting value should either remain 0, or be set to 10. You can find this using modulo:

possibleValues = {33, 21, 66, 35, 23, 40}

```
x = Min(possibleValues)
x = 21
y = x % interval    #You stated interval = 5
y = 1
StartingValue = x-y
StartingValue = 20
```

Notice the important line is commented out, and so the chart starts at zero:

[image: Unmodified]

Now with our line setting the property of the chart axis:

[image: Modified]

Here's the code:

```
Sub CreateChartWithStartValue()
    Dim x, y, interval As Integer
    Dim chart As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A7")
    Set chart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2
    chart.chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
    chart.chart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
    interval = 5
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
    y = x Mod interval
    chart.chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = x - y
End Sub
```

If this doesn't make sense, please don't downvote the answer, comment instead and we can clarify.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, that cannot be done in Excel.
But there is a workaround that emulates that quite well.
Setup a series, with x-values equal to those you want to have as tick labels, and y-values equal to y at the bottom of your chart.
(Later on, if you find you might need to change this ymin value, use a formula in each of the cells in this range referring to a single cell you modify.
You could even setup a user defined function that retrieves that value with [`Axis.MinimumScale`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.axis.minimumscale)).

Then add that series, and add labels to it using the same x values.
Place the labels below points.
I suggest you use [The XY Chart Labeler](http://appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm) by Rob Bovey ([his other utilities](http://appspro.com/Utilities/Utilities.htm) are also worth trying).
For the series choose no line and a marker of your choice, most likely a vertical line.
Fine tune the format.

I used this trick quite often for any kind of custom axis tick labels, e.g., inverse temperature scales, etc.

After using this for a while, I think I saw it more elaborated in [Jon Peltier's site](https://peltiertech.com/).
I strongly recommend his site for anything related to Excel charts.